# Insert into table stored procedure results plus variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert

I need to insert into a table the results of a stored procedure(SP) plus a couple of other variables.
I know how to insert the SP results but not the variables as well. Is there a way I can do this without having to write a separate update query or pass/return the variable into the SP.

I.e.

```
INSERT INTO contacttable(name, address, telnum)
EXEC GetContactDetails @ContactId

UPDATE contacttable SET linkId = @LinkId where id = @ContactId
```

Can I pass the @linkId variable into the INSERT in anyway rather than having to do the separate update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this the way you explain your current scenario is.

You either modify the proc to receive the extra parameter and you return it from there so that the insert statements already has this parameter, or you continue doing what you are doing.

Another possibility would be to change that proc into a table-valued function in a way that you can specifically select the columns you need from the resultset and you add the extra parameter in the insert. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO contacttable(name, address, telnum,linkid)
select name, address,telnum,@linkid from fnGetContactDetails(@ContactID)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've never used table-valued functions so will look into that method.